# Change pixels to fill with color in a WPF image

Tags: wpf, bitmap, pixel

I'm trying to fill an area of an image in WPF. Something similar to the bucket in Paint. How should I do this? I'm thinking of getting the pixel color under the mouse, and change all the pixels with the same color *near*. Is there a simpler way?

What should I use? WriteableBitmap?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [WriteableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx) is the best way to go on this one IMHO.